# How to access model instance from function in model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I wrote a function inside one of my Ember models that's designed to set some properties on the model instance. Below is a gross over-simplification of what the function is trying to do.

```
// In widget.js

export default DS.Model.extend({
  enabled: DS.attr('boolean'),
  ...
  turnOn() {
    this.set('enabled', true);
  }
});
```

I come from a Ruby background, so something like this feels very natural and appropriate, but this doesn't seem to work. I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a more appropriate way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong. `this` is the model instance. You are setting `enabled` on whatever model instance you called `turnOn` on. What is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`. Sorry, I probably should have put that in the question.

Comment: You are probably making a mistake out of the scope of the snippet posted. Here you can play around with a working example of what **I** understood you were trying to accomplish:

https://ember-twiddle.com/b771a325e63ef55d919e69bc456b5bef?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

Comment: @ThiagoPetrone I followed your link but the twiddle only seems to have an empty controller, a template, and twiddle.json

Comment: @ThiagoPetrone I just took another look and now it's populated. Thank you!

Comment: @Argus9 my bad:
https://ember-twiddle.com/b771a325e63ef55d919e69bc456b5bef?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

Comment: can you please show how & where you call `turnOn`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your controller/component action you are calling your model with `this.get("some_model").turnOn()`